# Mixing Html template with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, themes

i'm bit confused about Razor in MVC. I am newbie to RAZOR and MVC and has just created LOGIN and register page for practice. My boss asked me to put some Theme/Template and then integrate it with this code. My questions is:

1. Is it possible to integrate a theme being designed in HTML/CSS with Razor based syntax, i mean that i created my VIEWS of MVC RAZOR but now if i put HTML/CSS based theme with it then what complications or things are gonna arise ?

Answer (score 1):

yes. Super possible. Views are basically dynamic HTML.

simply copy the html to the view and once the view is rendered, you will see the entire html.
any place in the html you need to be dynamic while being rendered, you can use "@" sign and that will start c# code. then you may create c# code and add html in it too.

example:

```
@{
 string name = "Jovan";
 var dateOfBirth = new { Day = 8, Month = 12, Year = 1980 }; 
 string[] skills = new string[] { "MVC",  "C#", "JQuery", "ASP.NET" };
}


<h2>@name</h2>
<p>Born in year: @dateOfBirth.Year</p>
<ul>
@foreach(skill in skills){
 <li>skill</li> 
}
</ul>
```

in this example, you first fill up the values you are showing, and then you show them. here a for each runs against the number of skills that you filled in the array meaning 4 times can creates a "li" tag each and every time it runs.

Of course in most cases you dont do this. you create the values on the controllers or better yet service or business layers and then you pass it through a model to the view. so basically view just renders the information that is recieved from the controllers.

here is another example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Web Pages Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1> 
     <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in this example, the page will always render the current time and date of the server.

another example:

```
<select id="fieldStaffUsersListBox" multiple size="10">
    @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
    {
        <option value="@user.UserName">@user.FullName</option>
    }
</select>
```

here you are dynamically creating a select box which renders the list of the users that you have passed from the controller throgh the Viewmodel to the view.

you can use this tutorial to learn more:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

you'd have a whole lot to learn.

good luck :)